# Local nominatim openstreemap with Speed limits

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, nominatim

I'm currently running a local copy of the nominatim maps of openstreetmap on PostGIS.

Is there a way i can get the speed limits into this database so i can return that information as well.
I've found that this data is available when querying openstreetmap but require this to be returned locally

(I'm running our own local copy so i don't exceed there daily limits)

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably yes, if you modify Nominatim accordingly. That is, importing speedlimit information (the [maxspeed](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed) tag) into your database and adding it to query results. But there is no trivial way for just activating this feature.

Note that Nominatim is a geocoder and not made for querying all kinds of information from a OpenStreetMap database. For this tasks there are better solutions like [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Comment: Hi - Thankyou
Sorry for been slow in replying..
I'll take a look at the overpass API - i'd rather not edit my nominatim data.